# Cómo firmar un proyecto de xcode generado con ionic de forma automática

Tags: ionic, ios, xcode

Actualmente he intentado añadir las firmas en un build.json cuando hago ionic build, pero luego el schema no tiene las firmas bien seleccionadas. Me gustaría poder producir de forma automática desde línea de comandos el .ipa sin tener que detenerme a seleccionar las firmas cada vez que compilo.

Cuando genero el xarchive con xcodebuild creo que debe de haber algún parámetro para hacerlo, pero no encuentro nada.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí firmar poniendo al final del comando xcodebuild las variables:

```
CODE_SIGN_STYLE="Manual"
   PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="Nombre de tu provisioning profile"
   DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="Número development team"
   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Nombre (Numero)"
```